# How to increase multiple lines with <select> option on Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I got problem with `<select>` element on Firefox, It should list an option as text wrap like Google Chrome or Safari

[image: browser nightmare]

here is my CSS(SASS) code

```
select.form-control.bare-select{ 
    @include appearance(none);
    margin: 6px 0 10px;
    padding: 8px 24px 8px 12px;
    border: 1px solid $grey;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: $white url(/img/hero-select-caret.png) right center no-repeat;
    white-space: pre-line;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-size: 23px 50px;
    height: auto;
    color: $black;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.6;
    &:hover {
        color: darken($dark-blue, 10%);
    }
}
```

CodePen here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYVKoY

Comment: Can  you add your code to **Code Snippet** or  **jsfiddle.net**  it will help us to provide a solution to you

Comment: @LakmalAbesekara sure, here it is https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYVKoY